# input entry text with bind in tKinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, tkinter-entry

I created an entry widget inside a function.

```
search_1=Entry(okno, width=45)
search_1.grid( row=3, column=1)
#okno is main window of tK
```

Then I tried to get variable from it with

```
search_1.bind("<Return>", lambda event, a=search_1.get(), b="AUTOR": activate(a, b))
```

However function activate receives only b variable, which is a defined string. "a" variable which is supposed to be text from search_1 entry is not passed.
any idea why?

I tried to read that value (search_1.get()) in a activate function, but an entry widget is not global. I would prefer to use bind/lambda though.

Comment: You can always use `event.widget.get()` inside the function which is same as `search_1.get()`.

Comment: thanks, That did the trick. I also noticed, i didn't passed the event as a function argument. after fixing it, all works as intended. You have been a lot of help, thank You.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, remember to accept the answer so they get credit for their effort. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `search_1.get()` at the time the binding is *created*, not at the time that the user presses the return key.

You should stop using a lambda in this case and use a proper function. They are much easier to write, read, and debug. You can also leverage the fact that bound functions will passed an object that contains a reference to the widget that received the event. This makes the code less reliant on global variables, which is almost always a good thing.

```
def do_search(event):
    a=event.widget.get()
    b="AUTOR"
    activate(a, b)
...
search_1.bind("<Return>", do_search)
```

With that, you can much more easily debug issues.